# Using xcode 6 beta 6 we are unable to Create an ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode

We have been trying to create an ipa for xcode project working on swift using xcode 6 beta 6 (for Development). But unfortunately we are unable to create the ipa file. It would be great if some one could give solution for this.

The solution provided Dint solved my problem. Reconsider this question and solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try the solution accepted for that question?

Comment: If the problem is the same as the linked question, why shouldn't this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that solution but that dint solved my problem and as i was short of rep's so couldn't comment there. Hope u guys understand and post solution here. Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: Please give a vote up if this question is helpful. And Please Post some solution as we require this to test immediately.